# ClearCase snapshot views on ClearTeam Explorer

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-remote-client

I launched ClearTeam Explorer for the first time but I can't find how to setup snapshot views... Where are they located in the desktop CTE application? I see dynamic and web views only.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update 2015:

As mentioned below, since [ClearCase 8.0.1.6 (Dec 2014)](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21692526), snapshot views are supported ([release notes](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27037036)):

> #### CTE support for snapshot views
>
> **ClearTeam Explorer (CTE)** now supports snapshot views.
>   For more information, refer to the following technotes:
>
> - [1691355](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21691355): new features in CMAPI
> - [1691375](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21691375): about deliver/rebase operations
> - [1691401](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21691401): known issues

---

(original answer April 2014)
Web views are considered snapshot in CTE.

The difference is that the view server cannot reside on your local workstation: it only resides in the CTE server.

See "[Using ClearCase Web views](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v8m0r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.ccrc.help.doc/topics/t_use_web_views.htm)" and "[About ClearCase views](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v8m0r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.ccrc.help.doc/topics/c_ccview.htm)" for more.

> A Web view is a copy-based ClearCase view that is tolerant of high-latency connections to a CCRC WAN server, although it may be used in both wide-area network (WAN) and local area network (LAN) environments.
>
> Many of the ClearCase operations you can perform using Web views require an explicit connection to a CCRC WAN server. However, a subset of operations are available that can be used, even when you are disconnected from the CCRC WAN server.

(This is the part similar to a snapshot view:)

> A Web view uses a config spec to select a specific set of file and directory versions from one or more VOBs so that you can access them on your computer.
>   **Resources under source control must be loaded into a Web view before you can access them**.

Comment: I guess that web views are still accessible in my local workstation where CTE is installed, yes? If not - what's the point? that's the place where I need the.

Comment: @user1762109 you will load the content of those web views wherever you want in your local workstation. Only the view *server* is in the CCRC WAN server.

Answer (score 0):

Prior to 8.0.1.6 release ClearTeam Explorer supported only web views (over WAN) and dynamic views (over LAN). However, from ClearCase 8.0.1.6 release onwards, ClearTeam Explorer client supports snapshot views (over LAN). This means that locally registered snapshot views will be listed under My Views node in ClearTeam Navigator view. So you can browse through and perform source control operations on snapshot view resources. For more information, refer http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27037036