# Clear Team Explorer Supporting Snapshots

Tags: clearcase-ucm

This is a follow-up question of "[ClearCase snapshot views on ClearTeam Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23362051/6309)", about the actual installation.

I installed CTE plugin version 8.0.0 into Clearcase - and of course, I see the dynamic views just fine.
Now, I would like to see snapshots as well.

I see the discussion on `ccrc.zip` and `ccrc_extension.zip`.
And "[Rational ClearCase Release Notes version 8.0.1.x](http://Rational%20ClearCase%20Release%20Notes%20version%208.0.1.x)"

So do I need to update CTE 8.0.0 (already installed) to 8.0.1.6? Do I also somehow install ccrc.zip and ccrc_extension.zip.

I am using Helios version of Eclipse and find that IBM documents lacking on newer versions of Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

> do I need to update CTE 8.0.0 (already installed) to 8.0.1.6

Yes, or the CTE plugin wouldn't be able to display snapshot views.
But that assume that your ClearCase web server is also at least at 8.0.1.6.

The installation/update should be similar for newer version of Eclipse, but do check the [Rational ClearCase System requirements matrix](http://www-03.ibm.com/software/products/en/clearcase#tab_othertab1) to see if your version of Eclipse is supported.