# ClearTeam Explorer - CCRC - integrate with Beyond Compare

Tags: merge, diff, clearcase, beyondcompare, clearcase-remote-client

I am using IBM Rational Clear Case. Due the current world wide health situation, I am forced to work from home.

The best way and may be the only one, when using Visual Studio, is working with a Web View (Please correct me if there is a better way) - I assume this is called CCRC (Clear Case Remote Client). It is similar to a Snapshot View but without constant connection to the Clear Case server at work (This statement is not entirely correct).

When working with a snapshot view or for that matter with a dynamic view, I can change the setting to use Beyond Compare as the tool used for merge and compare in Clear Case.

Now for my questions:

1) Is there a way to do this also for ClearTeam Expolrer, which is where I control and manage my web view?

2) Any other workaround to use Beyond Compare with a web view?

Comment: Added the CCRC (Clear Case Remote Clients) term - which is probably a better definition for what I called: Web View.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer on IBM support page: [Changing the Diff/merge Type Manager in CCRC 7.1.1 and later](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/changing-diffmerge-type-manager-ccrc-711-and-later). Where it is explained how to change this setting in the ClearTeam Explorer.

The description do not exactly match my version of Clear Case (9.0.1.07) :

> 1. In CCRC 7.1, go to the menu
>
>    Window > Preferences > ClearCase Remote Client > Integration > Compare Merge > Manage Providers
>
>    [image: Blockquote]

Should probably be:

> 1. In ClearTeam Explorer, go to the menu
>
>    Window > Preferences > **IBM Rational ClearTeam Explorer** > Integration > Compare Merge > Manage
>
>    [image]

In addition the following is probably valid for `kdiff3.exe`:

> 3. Choose 'Supports Compare Operations'
>
>    Fill in the arguments for compare:
>
>    `%contribs% -fname "%filename1%" -fname "%filename2%"`
> 4. Choose 'Supports Merge Operations'
>
>    Fill in the arguments for merge: `%contribs% -o %merge_out%`

On [Scooter Software](http://www.scootersoftware.com/support.php?zz=kb_vcs#ccrc) site I actually found the correct arguments.

These are the modification for Beyond Compare:

> 3. Choose 'Supports Compare Operations'
>
>    Fill in the arguments for compare:
>
>    `%contribs% /vcs1="%filename1%" /vcs2="%filename2%"`
> 4. Choose 'Supports Merge Operations'
>
>    Fill in the arguments for merge:
>
>    `%contrib1% %contrib2% %base% /mergeoutput="%merge_out%"`

**My Settings example:**

[image]

- Make sure to write `BComp.exe` and not `BCompare.exe`. Because of that, I had a problem opening the compare more than once.

And:

[image: You need to select beyond compare and Apply the changes]

**Doing the instruction recommended by [IBM](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/changing-diffmerge-type-manager-ccrc-711-and-later) and [Scooter Software](http://www.scootersoftware.com/support.php?zz=kb_vcs#ccrc) did the trick and I could compare my code:**

[image]

Comment: !!! The IBM answer is general for any compare and merge tool, I am looking for the exact parameters to support Beyond Compare.

Comment: @VonC I completed my answer, thank you very much. Upvoted your links.

Comment: Fixed the answer. By mistake I used `BCompare.exe` instead of `BComp.exe` - Because of that, I had a problem doing compare more than once, without closing  the BeyondCompare app. Using the 'BComp.exe' solved this issue.

Comment: OK. I have also read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62163602/beyond-compare-integration-with-clearteam-explorer-ccrc-only-one-compare-at/62163603#62163603

Comment: @VonC, After fixing this answer, I deleted that question, as there is no point in having it.

Answer (score 1):

Using a [web view](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_9.0.2/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.ccrc.help.doc/topics/t_use_web_views.htm) is a good option, unless you can use directly snapshot views, as I [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23362460/6309) (CC8+)

In both cases (web view or snapshot view), the goal is to have the files copied on your local disk, to avoid network latency.

The problem is: ClearTeam Explorer does not come with a [`mgrs/map` file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3298184/6309) to modify for you to declare your own diff tool (be it Beyond Compare or WinMerge)

So I used to get two web views:

- one set to a fixed label
- one for working

That way, I could diff between the two separate view folders.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have found the answer on IBM Support page - may be I should have done a better research work before posting my question. Still the page is old so I added here the correction. As for you idea with two sets of views, is a good one! (also for other purposes - especially when there is no connection to the server).

Comment: OK the solution proposed by IBM is somewhat problematic I need to do some more checks on it. Currently for some reason the path is incorrect, e.g.:  **C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\RationalSDLC\clearcase\RemoteClient**_\ProjName.vcxproj@@HIJACKED_